# Android - Update Fragment in the tab activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-tabs, fragmenttransaction

I'm building an android application with a tab activity.
The tabs will be lists that when the user fire long press event 
in a determinated item in the list, a context menu will 
be opened and the user will be able to choose the option 
to edit that item.

To do this, i've created an actitivy that extends a FragmentActivity and implements an ActionBar.TabListener.

What i need to do is, when the user choose the option to edit an item, the form opens inside the tab of this list (the fragmentlist), updating the fragment of current tab.
I tried to use a FragmentTransaction in the List activity fragment, but, it didn't work.

The code i tried was the following (at the ListFragment)

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(),
                        newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); //
                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();
```

Somebody can help me? Thanks

EDIT: 
The layout of FragmentActivity is the following:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

The code of FragmentActivity is the following:

```
public class FiltroActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Filtro", "Diário", "Semanal" };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.filtro_activity);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

The code of the ListFragment is the following:

```
public class ListagemFragment extends ListFragment {
    public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Compromisso> {
        Context myContext;
        View v;
        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<Compromisso> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            myContext = context;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            v = convertView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listagem_item_activity,
                    parent, false);
            TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);
            TextView label2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtData);
            if (compromissos.size() > 0) {
                label.setText(compromissos.get(position).getTitulo());
                label2.setText("Data: "
                        + Formatter.GetShortDate(compromissos.get(position)
                                .getDataInicio(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
            }
            return row;
        }
    }
    List<Compromisso> compromissos;
    MyListAdapter myListAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getListaCompromisso();
        myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.listagem_item_activity, compromissos);
        setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
    }

    private void getListaCompromisso() {
        compromissos = new ArrayList<Compromisso>();
        CompromissoNegocio negocio = new CompromissoNegocio();
        compromissos = negocio.getListaCompromisso(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext());
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_listagem, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        int position;
        Intent i;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_item:
            info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            position = (int) info.position;
            CompromissoNegocio compNeg = new CompromissoNegocio();
            compNeg.Deletar(compromissos.get(position).getCompromissoID(),
                    getActivity());
            compromissos.remove(position);
            myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        case R.id.edit_item:
            info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            position = (int) info.position;
            EditActivity newFragment = new EditActivity();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(),
                    newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); //
            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
            Log.i("haha", "haha");

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getListaCompromisso();
        myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listagem_activity, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain bit more ? Where is the list and where do you need to show the form? What does the tabs contain?

Comment: I edited the question and added the relevant codes.

Comment: you have to set the item to the viewPager, Ex:  viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()) inside your onTabSelected(). Try this and let me know.

Comment: i tried it but nothing changed :( is just put the code that you've posted?

Comment: Did you get any error? Or does that fragments tabs working ?

Comment: The problem is not open the fragment list. The prpblem is when i try to change to edit fragment. After commit my fragment transaction, the list, i dont know, hide, but my edit fragment doesnt appear. After commit and 'hide' my list, when i press back button, my list show again.